# Using map, lambda and filter together to get squares fro multi-dimensional list

Tags: python

I came across an interesting challenge where I need to use map and lambda to filter out positive integers from a multidimensional list while maintaining its structure and return squares of the positive numbers. Following is the code that I tried. I have reached a point where I can filter out positive numbers but I am not able to square them.

```
# using map( <lambda here>, input) is mandatory
input = [[-1, 1, 2, -1, 3], [3, 4,-5]]
a = map(lambda x: list(filter(lambda y: y > 0, x)), input)
print(list(a))
```

Output I get is

```
[[1, 2, 3], [3, 4]]
```

Expected output is

```
[[1, 4, 9], [9, 16]]
```

What am I missing here? Is my approach wrong?

Comment: Could you share the original problem text?

Comment: You haven't actually attempted to square the positive numbers. You should try to code this, and then add your code.

Comment: Please don't use input word as a variable. It is a built in function, it may give you errors

Comment: @jarmod: That's what I have said. I am stuck here and I am not sure how can I square them. If I would have known how to square them, what would be the purpose of posting it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's reduce the lambda sillyness to the mandatory amount and use a normal list comprehension inside:

```
# using map( <lambda here>, input) is mandatory
input = [[-1, 1, 2, -1, 3], [3, 4,-5]]
a = map(lambda x: [y**2 for y in x if y > 0], input)
print(list(a))
```

(Keeping your `input` variable despite it shadowing the builtin function, as that looks like it's part of your spec.)

Comment: Thank you. This is much simpler. I was over-complicating it without reason.